# Passing variables to static block in magento2

Tags: customer, static-block

I have used below code in magento1 to load the static block with custom variables.

Here is the code of my m1 Block file.

```
 {
 $customer =  Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer();

    $block = Mage::getModel('cms/block')
        ->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())
        ->load('static_block_id');

    if($block->getIsActive()) {
        $array = array();

        $array['custom_value1'] = $formattedPrice = Mage::helper('core')->currency($customer->getNoofOrders(), true, false);
        $array['custom_value2'] = $formattedPrice = Mage::helper('core')->currency($customer->getSavingsToDate(), true, false);

        $array['registration_date'] = date('F Y', strtotime($customer->getRegistrationDate()));

        $filter = Mage::getModel('cms/template_filter');
        $filter->setVariables($array);

        // return the filtered block content.
        return $filter->filter($block->getContent());

}
```

Here **getNoofOrders** and **getSavingsToDate** are the custom customer attributes.

How can i use the same code in magento 2 format. If so please anybody help me with this how to set the custom variables and that is used in static blocks.
Thanks

Comment: Please check my answer.

Comment: Is it working ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use this below code :

```
protected $_customerSession;
protected $_blockFactory;
protected $_priceFormat;
protected $_filterProvider;
protected $storeManager;
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
    \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession,
    \Magento\Cms\Model\BlockFactory $blockFactory,
    \Magento\Framework\Pricing\Helper\Data $priceFormat,
    \Magento\Cms\Model\Template\FilterProvider $filterProvider,
    \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
    array $data = []
) {
    parent::__construct($context, $data);
    $this->_customerSession = $customerSession;
    $this->_blockFactory = $blockFactory;
    $this->_priceFormat = $priceFormat;
    $this->_filterProvider = $filterProvider;
    $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
}

public function yourFunction()
{
    $customer = $this->_customerSession->getCustomer();
    $block = $this->_blockFactory->create()->setStoreId($this->storeManager->getStore()->getId())->load('static_block_id');
    if($block->getIsActive()) {
        $array = [];
        $array['custom_value1'] = $formattedPrice = $this->_priceFormat->currency($customer->getNoofOrders(), true, false);
        $array['custom_value2'] = $formattedPrice = $this->_priceFormat->currency($customer->getSavingsToDate(), true, false);

        $array['registration_date'] = date('F Y', strtotime($customer->getRegistrationDate()));

        $filter = $this->filterProvider->getBlockFilter()->setStoreId($this->storeManager->getStore()->getId())->setVariables($array)->filter($block->getContent());

        return $filter;
    }
}
```

Hope, It may be helpful for you.

Comment: Happy to help !! Happy coding :)